# Can I trade Trophies with friends?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I just got super smash bros today and I was just wondering if the trophies you get in the game are tradeable and if they are how do you trade with friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot trade trophies. There's no such feature anywhere in the menus, this capability was not mentioned in any pre-release Miiverse posts or Nintendo Directs, and the previous game by the same team, *Kid Icarus: Uprising*, had similar collectibles (Idols) that also could not be traded between copies of the same game, despite there being other collectibles in that game (Weapon Gems) that were able to be shared via StreetPass.

You will eventually be able to transfer customization aspects (or at least some of them) with the upcoming Wii U version, but because [many of the trophies in each version are unique to that platform](https://miiverse.nintendo.net/posts/AYMHAAACAADRUqFpGGYsgQ), trophies cannot be transferred between versions, either.